# Array vs Map in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a complex structure that we are storing in mongo and a lot of processing is done on it and its updated frequently.

As part of the structure is having a Map of Map something like
`Map<Enum, Map<String, Object> data`

This is what is saved in mongo and is updated.

So the structure in mongo becomes something like

```
"data" : {
        "Category" : {     // Value of the enum
            "Test" : {     // Name of the value to categorize data with
                "count" : 2, 
                "values" : [
                  "value-1",
                  "value-2",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

The motivation behind keeping the structure like this is to speed the processing, as we need lot of lookups to add new data to same `Category` and `Name` and that is updated in mongo

Clearly now when we would need to add indexes and do complex query in future it won't be easy.

So looking for suggestion to change this to something more extendable ?

Reading about this looks like a structure something of this type would serve much better

```
List<MyObject> data;
```

Where MyObject is

```
Enum Category;
String Name;
int count;
List<String> values;
```

But as we would be processing on this data, finding everytime in a List would be much slower than doing a Map lookup.

Is there any way where we can have an Array type of schema in mongo but i can keep Map in my Java code for faster lookups ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep as array in mongodb and map in java is to transform it from array to map in server side.
We have many situations like that in my work and that what we usually do.

Also i would recommend you to simplify the documents you are storing in mongodb db. Try to convert your array values to single documents. It will involve a lot of redundancy but you earn more conceptual, indexing simplicity and increased query capability.
Also growing array within document will hurt write performance because it will rewrite everything to free the space because document space is continuous.

Observing your given document structure it seems that only valuable data you keep is actually a value inside value array.

So just break down you array into single documents.

```
{
    value: 'value-1'
},
{
    value: 'value-2'
},
{
    value: 'value-3'
},
```

Depends on the queries you are running against it, but structuring like this will give you more performance boost and querying freedom.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am new to mongo, can you please give an example for the updated mongo structure that you are suggesting

Comment: I added document structure suggestion to my answer